# How can you prevent "serrated" PNG image (aliasing) in Microsoft Report Viewer Report (PDF)

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, png, reportviewer

I have a PNG image (a triangle) which has the dimensions 200*200 pixels.
As per Paint.NET this corresponds to 5.29*5.29cm.

When I position this image in the Microsoft Report Viewer Report in my WPF application, the slanted sides are serrated and not smooth as in the PNG image.

**How can I ensure that the image is not "serrated" (aliased) in the Microsoft Report Viewer Report**

UPDATE: The same report when saved as TIFF does not show aliasing in the image. Does the saving as PDF cause the loss in quality of the external image?

Function used: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252131(v=vs.100).aspx

UPDATE: Sample application with issue:
http://1drv.ms/1hRcCFi

Comment: Could you perhaps provide some screenshots of how it looks in Paint.NET and your app?

Comment: It seems like this a render problem, when you print the report (even after exporting it as pdf) everything will be fine in my experience

Comment: The serration is also visible in the printout

Comment: Have you tried to use a different image?

Comment: If the source image is OK it is likely that saving as PDF is causing the issue as it is likely compressing your image as JPEG. Can you try changing the export settings for PDF for less image compression?

Comment: Good hint - I will check if Microsoft Report Viewer provides image compression settings.

Comment: I am exporting to PDF in local mode and there is no compression in this mode as per msdn forum entries.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was solved by replacing the "Transparent" to "White" in the background of the image used.

ReportViewer seems to have an issue with images using transparency.

Comment: The same thing happened to me and it was solved by removing the transparency, ReportViewer still to have an issue with images using transparency